# Ethernet (NIC) Stress Test

Tags: networking, benchmarking

I'm looking for a program/website to benchmark/stress a NIC (Network Interface card).

Before replacing it I want to make sure it really has a problem.

The problem is not the bandwidth itself, it is the system crashes (completely freezes) when a large number of connections are stablished.

System: Windows 7 x64

Comment: Should this software be gratis ? Which kind of connections ? Which amount of connections ?